# waking up arduino mini with a external signal

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, sleep

I have an arduino mini with an ultrasonic sensor conected to the pins 2 and 3, and a RGB LED connected to the 4,5, and 6, I want to include a wake up and sleep functionality that wakes up when receive a high signal in another pin as 7.

I have seen that normaly the pins for that are 2 and 3, as in the arduino web: [Arduino sleep web](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode)

But can it be done with another pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the normal external interrupts INT0 and INT1 you can also wake the chip through a variety of other interrupts. One of those is the *pin change* interrupt.

In the datasheet is a table of what is available in the different sleep modes, and what can wake you from that sleep mode. I have compressed the table to remove a lot of the stuff you don't care about at the moment and just show the "wake-up sources":

[image]

As you can see both INT and PCINT can wake from all modes (along with TWI [Wire.h] slave mode address matching).

The note (3) on the table just says that for INT0 and INT1 it must be a LOW level interrupt, not a RISING or FALLING. No mention is made of the type of interrupt for PCINT.

So yes, since pin 7 has PCINT facilities (all pins on the ATMega328P have PCINT) you can configure that as a wake-up source and wake the MCU using pin 7.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Mini has only two interrupt capable pins: 2 and 3. You have to move your sensor to other pin.

From the AtMega328p datasheet:

> If a level triggered interrupt is used for wake-up from Power-down,
>   the required level must be held long enough for the MCU to complete
>   the wake-up to trigger the level interrupt. If the level disappears
>   before the end of the Start-up Time, the MCU will still wake up, but
>   no interrupt will be generated. The start-up time is defined by the
>   SUT and CKSEL Fuses.

Comment: You forgot PCINT...

Comment: @Majenko. You are right. Your answer is better. What do i do?

Comment: There's not a lot you can do besides plagiarise ;) It's up to the OP to do whatever he fancies.